# Prestashop locally redirect all to home page

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have working shop on prestashop (1.6), when i copy files and db to local mashine, create virtual-host set up new shop-url, enable debug-mode, home page works but every other url (not home page) is redirecting to home page.

I have message:

```
[Debug] This page has moved
Please use the following URL instead: home-url-here
```

Regeneratig `.htaccess` file didnt help.

I cant find where is this redirect and how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In back-office "Preferences" -> "SEO en URLS"

Turn friendly url "Off" -> save and turn back "ON" (if required)

This should do the trick.

Comment: When I turn it off its OK, but when I turn this back on problem returns, and I need friendly urls working for debugging others problems.

Comment: You need to enable the "rewrite module" in apache in order to use Friendly URLs.
After enable restart your server; delete .htaccess file and turn friendly url OFF and back ON.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: 1. check if your setting are 100% the same as in the image: https://i.ibb.co/8m85Crd/Naamloos-1.jpg
2. Do you use any url-rewrite modules which you have bought?

Comment: Ad.1. I have presta 1.6 and settings are little different: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj0w2d1sf9sopl3/Zrzut%20ekranu%202020-03-16%2011.43.04.png?dl=0 Shop is not mine, I just started to administrating it. Ad.2. I think its only x13_redirect, but when I disable it every page display home page (content/.., category/..., etc)

Comment: Try to enable following setting: Advanced Parameters -> Performance -> Disable all overrides

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209702/discussion-between-crezzur-and-unbreak).